# AHK script to mimic Windows' show desktop feature on inactive windows only

Tags: customization, transparency, autohotkey

[image]Several utilities exist to make windows go transparent when inactive, but can an AHK script (or something else) be used to replicate Windows' show-desktop transparency effect on only inactive windows? I've not found a utility that does this.

Here is an example of what I want to achieve:

Comment: Yes it can be done with reasonable limitation as far as transparency is concerned.

Comment: Please upload the image here and embed it. Resources on SO should be independent of other sites and not everyone can access dropbox.com

Comment: Look up WinGetAll (function to get all windows) and WinSet (to control transparency). That should point you in the right direction.

Comment: If you want to imitate the look in your screenshot, I would rather create a "dummy gui" for each window with the same position/dimensions and hide/minimize the actual ones. You can then design the guis however you like (drawing shapes, outlining stuff etc.). When the gui is acivated, you can catch the event and replace it with the original window.